# How to zip and download a folder and subfolders from google storage in php / laravel

Tags: laravel-5, google-cloud-storage

I want to download a folder (not a file) and all included subfolders and files from my bucket in google cloud storage. I'd prefer zip them all first. I'm developing the project with Laravel which is deployed in App Engine flex. What would be the most efficient way to do that? I have sought all over the web but have just found solutions for files.
Any help would be appreciated.
Regards!